# Button on click not working on first click

Tags: android

when I click on the button for the first click click function doesn't work but for the second time click on-click function works. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Please suggest me right way. Thanks in advance

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            ImageView deletelist = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dltconsumer);
            final CustomFontTextView number = (CustomFontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.consumer_number);

            deletelist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    JSONArray delete_jsonarray;
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    String phonenumber = number.getText().toString();
                    String jsonsetpreference_data = SessionManager.getPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer");
                    Log.d("jsonsetpreference_data:::::::","" +jsonsetpreference_data);
                    try {
                        delete_jsonarray= new JSONArray(jsonsetpreference_data);
                        for (int i =0; i<= delete_jsonarray.length()-1 ; i++){
                            jsonObject = delete_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String array_phonenumber = jsonObject.getString("number");
                            if (phonenumber.equals(array_phonenumber)){
                                delete_jsonarray.remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                        SessionManager.setPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer",delete_jsonarray.toString());

                        String data = SessionManager.getPreferences(context,"splitfare_consumer");

                        Log.d(TAG,""+data);

                        ArrayList<String> details = new  ArrayList<String>();
                        try {
                            js = new JSONArray(data);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        adapter = new AddPassengerAdapater(context,js,details);
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you got it working now?

Answer (score 1):

Simply reading the code above : When onItemClick is called, you setOnClickListener on some image view. This is one click. The only thing done here is setting the listener.

Then, on further clicks, the ImageView's onClick will be called.

You should consider either using directly the onItemClick of the ListView, or adding the following attributes in your ImageView's xml :

```
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="yourMethodNameHere"
```

Comment: I don't know which of the two solutions you tried, but if you tired the xml one, be sure to replace `"yourMethodNameHere"` with an existing method in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

why you use listview? that is because the button is inside listview I guess..

You can use Recyclerview with onItemClick, please refer to this tutorial 
https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

hope this help you